# Should we have a custom profile covering bicycle specs?

Tags: feature-request

It is bit tiresome to have to describe your main bicycle over and over. Couldn't Bicycles have a bicycle profile (sure some people would have multiple bicycles with wheel size, its picture, tire pressure, bicycle type, common usage, carrying capacity needed? Anyone wish to specify what specifications to include.

Comment: I ended up registering all my bikes in https://project529.com/garage/bikes  but there's no way to make your collection public.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a question tight to a specific bike, better to repeat the configuration in each question.

1. bikes can be modified
2. you can buy/get rid of/sell bikes.

So every question that would refer to the description in the profile would technically be "invalidated" if you change something in the profile. There are already some rules stating that answers should be self-sufficient, I think that questions should even more.

Answer (score 2):

I've got this information in my profile, which is visible at https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/users/19705/criggie?tab=profile

Does that serve your requirements?

Comment: I like that. Straightforward and optional.  And listing your current N is a nice touch.

Comment: @TedHohl and your comment made me go check and update it. Things had moved on in 5 months.